# .htaccess redirect and auth. header

Tags: php, angular

I have an Angular 2 App hosted on my site. 
This app sends a jwt token in the authentication header.

So my services on server side can fetch this token.

So far this works, but if my route is 404 it should redirect to an /index.html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
```

Im not really a .httaccess pro how can i catch this 404s

Answer (score 0):

try to redirect not by your server but by angular router:

```
{path: '', component: HomeComponent},
 ....
 {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}//set this at the end of your routes
```